# Choosing fields in Facebook graph v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently upgraded from using Facebook graph v1.0 to using the latest v2.2 and am having trouble migrating over some existing functionality.

I am trying to get the profile pictures along with some other data from the "me/home" request.

My old code was this https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/me/home?fields=id,from.picture, from.id,to.picture, to.id, story, picture, link, name, description, type, status_type, created_time.

The new graph api doesn't allow the "from.picture" to be completed. How do I get the profile picture included in the "me/home" request?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: In the v2.2 version you only have the id from the "me/home" request, so i think you have to make another call to get the "id" profile picture and other data.

Comment: It seems odd to me that they would rip out functionality as they go from one version to the next

Comment: they didn´t "rip out functionality", they mainly improved privacy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still possible to get the picture of the poster in one call, with field expansion:

```
/me/home?fields=from{name,picture}
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#fieldexpansion

Comment: there is issues with curly brackets and requests made from ios